# Switch between multiple windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created few windows using Tkinter. I need help in the implementation of switching from one window to another when the button has been clicked.
All windows that are created should have the same size.
And also I want to clear existing window data and show next window data.

Comment: you can create many `Frame` with different contents and use `pack()` to show frame in window and `pack_forget()` to hide it. This way you can change content in one window using buttons.

Comment: Can u show me a simple example. Without frames is there any other way to switch Windows automatically closing existing one and appearing new window

Comment: there is method to close one window - `root.destroy()` - and create new one - `root = tkinter.Tk()` - but it is weird. Did you see program which destroys window to change content ? But if this resolves your problem then use it.

Comment: [examples which use Frame to change contents](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/__frame__/replace-frame-with-content). See main-v1.py and main-v2.py. v3-classes is not ready.

Comment: [example which replace Window using root.destroy() and root=tkinter.Tk()](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/__window__/replace-window)

Comment: I fixed the grammar to make the question more clear and understandable.

Comment: fixing grammar and making the question more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple windows opened and want to switch between each window with all of their widgets intact then I don't think destroying a window each time you switch is a good idea instead you can try to `withdraw` and `deiconify` the windows.

I've created something like this which can switch between windows and maintain the same geometry of the previous window as you said.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    # List to keep the reference of all the toplevel windows
    _info_pages = []

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        kw = tk._cnfmerge( (cnf,kw) )
        width = kw.pop('width', master.winfo_width())     # 250x250 will be the standard size of the window
        height = kw.pop('height', master.winfo_height())
        title = kw.pop('title', 'Win %s' %(len(self._info_pages)+1) ) 
        super(Window, self).__init__(master=master, cnf=cnf, **kw)
        for i in self._info_pages: i.wm_withdraw() # Hide the previous windows 
        if self._info_pages and width == master.winfo_width():
            self.wm_geometry(self._info_pages[-1].winfo_geometry())
        else:
            self.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, 
                master.winfo_rootx()+master.winfo_width(), master.winfo_rooty()))
        self._info_pages.append(self)
        self.title(title)
        self.B1 = tk.Button(self, text='◀ Prev', padx=5, command=self.switch_to_prev)
        self.B1.place(relx=0, rely=1, anchor='sw')

        self.B2 = tk.Button(self, text='Next ▶', padx=5, command=self.switch_to_next)
        self.B2.place(relx=1, rely=1, anchor='se')

        self.enable_disable_button()

    def enable_disable_button(self):
        """Enable and disable the buttons accordingly if there is no window."""
        for i in self._info_pages:
            if i == self._info_pages[0]: i.B1['state'] = 'disabled'
            else: i.B1['state'] = 'normal'
            if i == self._info_pages[-1]: i.B2['state'] = 'disabled'
            else: i.B2['state'] = 'normal'

    def switch_to_prev(self):
        """Switch to the previous window"""
        index = self._info_pages.index(self)
        if index != 0:
            for i in self._info_pages:
                i.wm_withdraw()
            self._info_pages[index-1].geometry(self.winfo_geometry())
            self._info_pages[index-1].wm_deiconify()

    def switch_to_next(self):
        """Switch to the next window"""
        index = self._info_pages.index(self)
        if index+1 != len(self._info_pages):
            for i in self._info_pages:
                i.wm_withdraw()
            self._info_pages[index+1].geometry(self.winfo_geometry())
            self._info_pages[index+1].wm_deiconify()

    def destroy(self):
        """if a window is destroyed this will open the last window in the list"""
        self._info_pages.remove(self)
        if self._info_pages:
            self._info_pages[-1].geometry(self.winfo_geometry())
            self._info_pages[-1].wm_deiconify()
            self.enable_disable_button()
        return super().destroy()

# This is just a demo
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random as rnd

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('250x250')
    root.title("I'm the main window")
    colorlist = ['beige','bisque','black','blanchedalmond','blue','blueviolet', 
                'burlywood', 'cadetblue','chartreuse','chocolate' ]
    def create_window():
        Window(root, bg=rnd.choice(colorlist))

    tk.Button(root, text='Create Window', command=create_window).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```